# Does one can detect previous OS data on memory card of Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, privacy, shred

1) I freshly installed Ubuntu Mate on Raspberry Pi and updated it and installed all required packages I need. Then I create disk image of that SD Card using Card Reader on Another PC as 'Backup Image'.

2) Then I use that SD card with that OS on Raspberry Pi for while..

3) After that I shred the whole SD Card using Shred Utility and restored the Backup Image previously Created.

Now Does anyone with sufficient knowledge and time can find my old OS data or my user activity during my uses in (2) above?

Comment: "Physical destruction may be necessary to securely erase devices such as memory cards and unusable hard disks." Source [shred (Unix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shred_(Unix))

Answer (score -1):

As the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shred_(Unix)) on shred says, it's possible that some data still exists, even though you used it on the entire SD card.  This is because it can only erase every logical block of data and, due to wear leveling, this doesn't necessarily correspond with every physical block of data.

But in the grand scope of things, you have to think about your threat model: who you're defending against, and just how valuable the data is you're defending.  Nothing short of a hammer will guarantee that your data is destroyed, but if you're just selling it on eBay and are worried that a buyer could read your browsing history, shredding should be perfectly sufficient.